# Openssh - Allow root access sftp and ssh in the same server

Tags: networking, server, permissions, ssh, sftp

I want to configure sftp on my server to be accessed by root user.

I changed my configuration of `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to:

```
PermitRootLogin yes
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys
PermitEmptyPasswords yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
Compression no
ClientAliveInterval 15
ClientAliveCountMax 4
#Other options are commented
[...]
Subsystem sftp /usr/libexec/sftp-server

Match user root
ChrootDirectory /
X11Forwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

It works and I can connect by sftp to my server, but now I can connect by ssh anymore. I got this message:

`This service allows sftp connections only.`

The same happen with `Match group root`

How can I configure sftp to allow root but keeping ssh too?

---

### Update:

Commenting ForceCommand internal-sftp option ssh still works but I cannot connect by sftp.
sshd_config:

```
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/libexec/sftp-server
Match user root
ChrootDirectory /
X11Forwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
#ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Error:

```
user@notebook:~$ sftp root@my_device
Warning: the ECDSA host key for 'my_device' differs from the key for the IP address 'xx.xx.xx.xx'
Offending key for IP in /home/myUser/.ssh/known_hosts:78
Matching host key in /home/myUer/.ssh/known_hosts:93
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Connection closed.  
Connection closed
```

Note: If I also remove `Subsystem   sftp    /usr/libexec/sftp-server` as I got a different error when trying to connect by sftp:
`subsystem request failed on channel 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem here was that `/usr/libexec/sftp-server` doesn't exist in the server side. I added it in the image with a new Yocto build and then I was able to connect by ssh and sftp with root using the default config:

```
# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/libexec/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   X11Forwarding no
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   PermitTTY no
#   ForceCommand cvs server
```

Answer (score 2):

You used `ForceCommand internal-sftp` for user root, which forces every connection from root to use sftp. Remove this command (or comment it out) - both ssh and sftp should normally work for root (do not forget to restart sshd after config change of course).

Comment: I updated the post with some tests. If I remove `ForceCommand internal-sftp` ssh works, but I'm not longer able to connect by sftp

Comment: Is the `sshd_config` file you published the **full** file or do you have some other lines in it? If the latter, please publish the **full** config.  To debug the issue, I would start with something simple -  commenting the whole section after `Match user root` (including that line) and check if with only `PermitRootLogin yes` both ssh and sftp work for root. If it works, then some of the options specified after `Match user root` is causing trouble. You can also run the ssh server in debug mode and check if it logs anything.